# Remove save keyboard shortcut using script

Tags: libreoffice-basic

Let's assume I need to remove the Ctrl+S keboard shortcut that is used to save a document in Libreoffice writer.

I can change the function using this code...

```
        <node oor:name="S_MOD1" oor:op="replace">
          <prop oor:name="Command">
            <value xml:lang="en-US">.uno:Test</value>
          </prop>
        </node>
```

But how do I delete the function? I do not want .uno:test to appear in the function list.

Full code:

https://gist.github.com/shantanuo/0730c8e759aeb4b454bc0105e327641a

I do not want to use tools - Customize option. I need to do this programmatically.

Answer (score 0):

What are you trying to do? What is your end goal? Correct me if I'm wrong, but you want to bind it to a function but not have the function show up?

AFAIK you can go into `Tools>Customize>Keyboard>Shortcut Keys` to set and change the shortcuts. You can even go down to see what function to bind Ctrl+S to.

Have you tried naming it   (empty space)?

Comment: Please avoid the impression of asking a question where an answer should be. Please [edit] and try for [answer].